# Where can I change the "add to cart" text on product page?

Tags: magento2, template

Where can I change the "Add to cart" or in German "Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen" Text on the product page? Where is that template file and where do i need to copy it in my custom theme?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find out it in

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
```

You can change it from your theme by extend this file.

Otherwise also you can change by Csv translate file

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackage/i18n/[Your_Language_Code].csv

"Add to Cart","um Warenkorb hinzufügen"
```